# PHP Upload Form: Why isn't my multipart/form-data form sending any POST data? (LARGE FILE UPLOADING)

Tags: html, post, upload, multipartform-data

i'm uploading a **70mb ZIP file**. perhaps debugging may be putting things out of sync? when i don't have the file in the file input, i get the post data, but when i do, the post data is empty.

```
<form method="post" action="load_statements.php?action=load" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

i have fields (with the name attribute) and a submit button inside the form. however, when i try to access them, i get:

```
Notice: /fiq_local/load_statements.php line 33 - Undefined index: statementType
Notice: /fiq_local/load_statements.php line 45 - Undefined index: year
Notice: /fiq_local/load_statements.php line 47 - Undefined index: idVar
Notice: /fiq_local/load_statements.php line 49 - Undefined index: attachment
```

they all follow the same syntax. here is one:

```
$statementType = $_POST['statementType'];
```

it seems that the upload is taking a long time, so i'm guessing it's the problem. how can i deal with a large file upload and still get the post data?

i set the following in my php.ini:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

Comment: Make sure that form start and ending tags match, there is no mis-match of `<form>` tag, for example closing at wrong place.

Comment: i've looked it over and it looks fine to me :( but i've put up both the php and generated html code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it all had to do with the php configurations!

you need:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
```

and

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 1000M
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest.

Comment: Thanks for posting your fix, got me thinking in the right direction.  A point to note when uploading multiple files, is that upload_max_filesize limits each individual file, but post_max_size is the limit for all files together.  Obvious, really, but had me scratching my head for too long!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure those indexes exist in `$_POST`? The only way I've ever solved this problem is by using `isset()` before using the var. However, it appears you are doing that.

Therefore, I am going to leave my recommendation at turn off `E_NOTICE` error reporting in your production code:

`error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`

Comment: i forgot to add another important piece of info:
i'm upload a 70mb ZIP file
could debugging maybe put things out of sync? when i don't have the file in the file input, i get the post data, but when i do, the post data is empty.